# How to create multiple tables using SQFLite in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `sqflite` for database. When I try to create one table it works perfectly. But when I add some additional `SQL` code to create extra tables I get this error:

```
error DatabaseException(near ",": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE deletednotes(id INTEGER PRIMARY, title TEXT, description TEXT, priority INTEGER, date int)) sql 'CREATE TABLE deletednotes(id INTEGER PRIMARY, title TEXT, description TEXT, priority INTEGER, date int)' args []} during open, closing...
```

How can I create multiple tables properly?

Here is my queries:

```
  void _createDB(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute('''CREATE TABLE $notetable(
          $COL_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, $COL_TITLE TEXT, $COL_DESCRIPTION TEXT, $COL_PRIORITY INTEGER, $COL_DATE int)''');

    await db.execute(
        '''CREATE TABLE $archievedtable($COL_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, $COL_TITLE TEXT, $COL_DESCRIPTION TEXT, $COL_PRIORITY INTEGER, $COL_DATE int)''');

    await db.execute(
        '''CREATE TABLE $deletedtable($COL_ID INTEGER PRIMARY, $COL_TITLE TEXT, $COL_DESCRIPTION TEXT, $COL_PRIORITY INTEGER, $COL_DATE int)''');
  }
```

There can be some syntax errors maybe, any ideas?

- const variables:

````
  static const COL_TITLE = "title";
  static const COL_DESCRIPTION = "description";
  static const COL_PRIORITY = "priority";
  static const COL_DATE = "date";

  String notetable = "notes";
  String deletedtable = "deletednotes";
  String archievedtable = "archievednotes";```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `int` in your sql code with `INTEGER` and  change the following 
line to add the keyword `KEY` after declaring the primary key:

`await db.execute(
        '''CREATE TABLE $deletedtable($COL_ID INTEGER PRIMARY, $COL_TITLE TEXT, $COL_DESCRIPTION TEXT, $COL_PRIORITY INTEGER, $COL_DATE int)''');`.

To:

`await db.execute(
        '''CREATE TABLE $deletedtable($COL_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, $COL_TITLE TEXT, $COL_DESCRIPTION TEXT, $COL_PRIORITY INTEGER, $COL_DATE int)''');`

Comment: same error again. any ideas on creating multiple tables using `sqflite` in flutter?

Comment: sorry i missed it, the error is actually said it all. The word `KEY` is missing in the line `CREATE TABLE $deletedtable($COL_ID INTEGER PRIMARY, $COL_TITLE TEXT, $COL_DESCRIPTION TEXT, $COL_PRIORITY INTEGER, $COL_DATE int)''');`  when declaring the primary key.

Comment: that is it! appreciate your help, update answer, I will approve.